# 169-algorithm in C language

Tags: c, recursion

I need to write a program with the 169-algorithm in the C language. However, I seem to get an infinite loop until the program crashes.

For any natural number `n`, the operation of “inverting and adding” consists of inverting the digits of `n` and adding up the
value of `n`. For example, consider `n = 345`. Inverting its digits we obtain the number `543`. Now we have to add `n` to this number, that is,
`n + 543 = 345 + 543 = 888`. For most of natural numbers this process, repeated reiteratively, ends up producing a number which is
palindrome. For instance, number `59` produces the sequence `59`, `154`, `605`, and `1111`, as `(59 + 95) = 154`, `(154 + 451) = 605`, and `(605 + 506) = 1111`. The function can assume that the initial call to the function will always be done with a number which, at some point, obtains a palindrome number.

This is the code that have so far:

```
int invert_int(int n, int m) {
    int div = n / 10; //Divide n by 10
    if (div == 0)
        return (n + m * 10); //If the division is equal to 0, then return n*+m*10
    return (invert_int(div, n % 10 + m * 10)); //If not, calculate the inverse of it again
}

int calc(int num) {
    int sum = 0; //Declare sum as 0
    int inum = invert_int(num, 0); //Calculate the inverse of num by calling invert_int, having the number and 0 as parameters
    //If num=inum, then it's a palindrome
    if (num == inum) {
        return sum; //Return sum to end
    } else {
        sum = num + inum; //sum = number + inverted number
        printf("%d + %d = %d", num, inum, sum); //Print the previous sum
        sum = sum + calc(num); //Add the next number to sum
        return sum;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int input; //Declare variable to store the user's input
    printf("Introduce a number:"); 
    scanf("%d", &input); //Scan a number
    printf("%d", calc(input)); //Print the result of the calculation by calling calc with 'input' as argument
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I don't seem to see the problem here. Could anybody help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "However, I seem to get an infinite loop until the program crashes." Better to post the input used or even better, just code `printf("%d", calc(/* Substitute here */ The_input_that_caused_the_problem));`  BTW: did you write this code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `calc` method should be

```
int calc(int num){
  int sum = 0; //Declare sum as 0
  int inum = invert_int(num,0); //Calculate the inverse of num by calling invert_int, having the number and 0 as parameters
//If num=inum, then it's a palindrome
  if(num==inum){
    return num; //Return sum to end <--- change here
  }else{
    sum=num+inum; //sum = number + inverted number
    printf("%d + %d = %d",num,inum,sum); //Print the previous sum
    return calc(sum); <--- just call `calc` again.
  }
}
```

Earlier you are calling `calc` with wrong parameters and every time it branched with the same number but the next call was never the same. There is no need to pass the `sum = sum + calc(num);` num again in `calc()`. This created the infinite loop.

Also to give an explanation for the changes I made - the thing is whenever you are dry running the algorithm - you are first calculating the number and reverse number and then you checked both of the. If they don't match do you pass the real number? No. You pass the sum of them and that's what is being done here.

Comment: NMDV, yet OP has not demonstrated de-bugging efforts.  Even good answers then may encouraging [no effort to debug the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @chux.: You know me at least in SO domain and I don't support it. I like solving problems at times...the OP even after giving this answer, if tries to get the idea - OP will learn the algorithm or the idea. If OP wouldn't try that I can ensure you that OP won't learn anything even if answer is not provided. OP would copy from friend's and will try to post it in other forums etc. True learner won't stop at an answer. Also if your question is why did I answer? I answered because it posed a bit of challenge to detect it (Yes it is very small but there is some)...I like it like all of you guys.